# SSIS Flat File Source Advanced Editor, Is there a way to change all data types at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

When I connect my flat file source to my destination, I always get the error message.

"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

The way I have been solving it is by manually going into the Advanced Editor in the Flat File source, Advanced Editor and going into the Input and Output tab and changing the data type directly for each column here. There's got to be an easier way to do this. Some of my tables has so many columns and it is time consuming. Is there a way to manually change it once, then save the change and use it for the next flat file source?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this from `Flat File Connection manager` not from the `Flat File Source` or `Flat File Destination`

1. Open the `Flat File connection manager`  --> `Advanced Tab`
2. Select all columns and change the data types
3. When finished go to `Flat File Source` and revalidate it *(double click on it)*

**Workaround** *(not recommended)*

Open the dtsx file using a text editor or notepad (it is an xml file), select for the `Flat File Source` part, find and replace Data types.